# Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?

Tags: android, layout, draw

I would like to draw a line right in the middle of a layout and use it as a separator of other items like TextView. Is there a good widget for this.  I don't really want to use an image as it would be hard to match the other components to it.  And I want it to be relatively positioned as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 1841):

I usually use this code to add horizontal line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

To add vertical separator, switch the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values

Comment: Works for me too. Can also add android:layout_marginTop="2dp" (etc) to add spaces in top and bottom.

Comment: This is great for a simple horizontal line.  But if you want the color fading at the ends, use one of the other methods here.

Comment: Or even better, use `layout_height="2dp" and android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"`

Comment: yeah or just use html color code for yellow.  that background value gave me an error.       android:background="#FFFF00"

Comment: I had to add `android:minHeight="1dp"` to make the line in my layout visible. I haven't been able to figure out the reason yet.

Comment: I cannot put this View inside LinearLayout / FrameLayout error inflating android.view.View. What did I miss?

Comment: I added margin top and bottom, it makes it even more awesome :)

Comment: You should use px instead of dp for dividers. Unless you actually want the divider size to vary and, potentially, drop below 1/2 pixels. :)

Comment: Material design specification recommends use 1dp thick http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dividers.html#dividers-specs

Comment: You can also use margin attributes for a more convincing divider.
For horizontal dividers
`android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"`
For Vertical dividers
`android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"`

Comment: Any idea on how to put a word in between the separator?

Comment: @AlexKucherenko: The material design specs don't seem to specify this anymore (at least I couldn't find that). Also, FYI, there seems to be a special component planned for use as a separator (https://material.io/design/components/dividers.html#implementation), instead of a styled View.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553069/12865125) answer for using [MaterialDivider](https://material.io/components/dividers/android#using-dividers) as a solution.  I found 1.5.0-alpha01 worked for me but 1.5.0-alpha04 has a bug.

Comment: In widget section of Android Studio Palette, you can find a Horizontal Divider. You may skip creating a empty view and use the provided feature.

Answer (score 695):

To improve on the answers provided by [Alex Kucherenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228514/alex-kucherenko) and [Dan Dar3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308836/dan-dar3)

I added this to my styles:

```
<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>
```

Then in my layouts is less code and simpler to read.

```
<View style="@style/Divider"/>
```

Comment: This seems to work but in Android Studio preview with API 21 it isn't shown... I couldn't test if this is only a problem of the preview or also on real devices...

Comment: Very nice, I just added the id and layout_below because I have a lot of Views

Comment: I thought it wasn't being shown in the Android Studio preview as well, but after zooming in on the preview I can make out the faint line that is displayed.

Comment: I like the idea, but for me, using `?android:attr/listDivider` as the background resulted in the line being invisible. When I changed it to `@android:color/darker_gray`, it was visible. Maybe I have my theme set up wrong...

Comment: Be aware that putting `android:layout_` attributes in styles is not recommended. Such attributes are meant to describe the relationship between that view and its parent. For example, <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item> might have very different results when applying this style to a parent ConstraintLayout vs. a LinearLayout or FrameLayout. For a detailed info, see: https://tips.seebrock3r.me/where-do-layout-attributes-belong-4d7fd5eaa1fa

Comment: I tried to use a layout along with <include> but faced issues where I had to repeat the width & height properties in the <include>, along with other issues such as margins not working. This implementation worked first try.

Answer (score 137):

Add this in your layout where you want the divider (modify the attributes to fit your need):

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Looking especially nice in DrawerLayout

Comment: @Ahmed You cannot use this when you have white activity background I suppose, in that case use android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" instead.

Comment: All the answers that make use of android:height="1dp" is not correct for me. The divider is still very thick compared to the default divider rendered in a ListView. Also tried android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:orientation="vertical" but nothing got rendered though.

Answer (score 114):

You can use this in `LinearLayout` :

```
android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:orientation="vertical" >            

        <TextView 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="abcd gttff hthjj ssrt guj"/>

        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcd"/>
        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcd gttff hthjj ssrt guj"/>

        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcd"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note that this is only available from API level 11

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not highlight the dividers with bold colors.

Comment: less is better! Thanx

Comment: Or android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"> to show divider at top and bottom too

Answer (score 94):

## Easiest Way:

### Vertical divider :

#### `<View style="@style/Divider.Vertical"/>`

[image: Vertical divider view]

### Horizontal divider :

#### `<View style="@style/Divider.Horizontal"/>`

[image: Horizontal divider view]

### That's all yes!

Just put this in `res>values>styles.xml`

```
<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item> //you can give your color here. that will change all divider color in your app.
</style>

<style name="Divider.Horizontal" parent="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item> // You can change thickness here.

</style>

<style name="Divider.Vertical" parent="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this overlaps the entire thing with a View.

Answer (score 61):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/connect_help"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" />
```

Comment: I would defend this method more that others on the account that it uses an already existing style, but it might not please everybody.

Comment: The drawback of this approach is, however, poor Android does NOT guarantee existing style.

Answer (score 48):

use this code. It will help

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >
```

Answer (score 34):

```
<View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Between two Layouts Put this code to get Divider.

Comment: same result, fewer code compared to other answers. thanks

Answer (score 28):

Just write this :

```
 android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
 android:showDividers="middle"
```

full example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTipInformation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvServiceRating"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main.msg.tippercent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main.msg.tiptotal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer as it is the most correct way of adding a divider to a `LinearLayout`

Comment: This will be for all elements in the layout ,, corrent ?

Answer (score 18):

if you use actionBarSherlock, you can use the [com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout.java) class in order to support dividers and show them between the views .

example of usage:

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerPadding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end" >
... children...
```

res/drawable/divider.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <size android:height="2dip" />

    <solid android:color="#FFff0000" />

</shape>
```

do note that for some reason, the preview in the graphical designer says "android.graphics.bitmap_delegate.nativeRecycle(I)Z" . not sure what it means, but it can be ignored as it works fine on both new versions of android and old ones (tested on android 4.2 and 2.3) .

seems the error is only shown when using API17 for the graphical designer.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this `<View>` element just after the First TextView.

```
 <View
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10dp"
         android:id="@+id/view1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

Its very simple. Just create a View with the black background color.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000"/>
```

This will create a horizontal line with background color. You can also add other attributes such as margins, paddings etc just like any other view.

Answer (score 12):

Adding this view; that draws a separator between your `textviews`

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is your answer..this is an example to draw line between controls...

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="FaceBook Feeds" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp"
             android:background="#d13033"/>

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

This code draw line between two controls...

Answer (score 10):

It adds a horizontal divider to anywhere in your layout.

```
    <TextView
       style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: The line goes only under the Textview.

Answer (score 9):

Runtime version:

```
View dividerView = new View(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, UIUtils.dpToPix(getContext(), 1));
dividerView.setLayoutParams(lp);

TypedArray array = getContext().getTheme()
    .obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {android.R.attr.listDivider});
Drawable draw = array.getDrawable(0);       
array.recycle();

dividerView.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
mParentLayout.addView(dividerView);
```

Answer (score 8):

**use this xml code to add vertical line**

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

**use this xml code to add horizontal line**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//for vertical line:

<View
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#00000000" />




//for horizontal line: 

<View
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:background="#00000000" />
//it works like a charm
```

Answer (score 6):

In cases where one is using `android:layout_weight` property to assign available screen space to layout components, for instance

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

     /* And we want to add a verical separator here */

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
        ...
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

To add a separator between the existing two layouts which has taken the entire screen space already, we cannot just add another LinearLayout with `android:weight:"1"` because that will make three equal width columns which we don't want. Instead, we will decrease the amount of space we will be giving to this new layout.
Final code would look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

                    /* *************** ********************** */

    /* Add another LinearLayout with android:layout_weight="0.01" and 
       android:background="#your_choice" */
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     />

    /* Or View can be used */
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     />

                     /* *************** ********************** */

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to use it a lot, best thing to do is

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="Seperator">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_color</item>
    </style>
```

now in your layout, just add it like:

```
<View style="@style/Seperator" />
```

Answer (score 4):

To complete Camille Sévigny answer you can additionally define your own line shape for example to custom the line color.

Define an xml shape in drawable directory. line_horizontal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    <size android:width="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Use this line in your layout with the wished attributes:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

Comment: without using android:src="?android:attr/listDivider"  .... just add android:background="#FFFFFF"

Answer (score 4):

Add a horizontal black line using this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use this code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#aa000000" />
```

if you have an object in your layout and you want set line below that use this attribute in ImageView:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textBox1"
```

Answer (score 3):

This would help you to resolve this problem.
Here a small view is created to make a black line as a separator between two views.

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
         />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/divider" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code " a horizontal divider line between two Text Views".
Try this

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="5dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text:"address" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" 
        android:text:"Upload File" />/>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple solution

just add this code in your layout and replace 'Id_of__view_present_above' to the id of the view, below which you need the divider.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="#c0c0c0"
  android:id="@+id/your_id"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/Id_of__view_present_above"
/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  Look for-> `Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.`

Answer (score 1):

Divide the space in two equal parts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="end"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that one part contains a divider at the end

Answer (score 0):

For example if you used recyclerView for yours items:

in build.gradle write:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
```

If you want to set color, size and margin values, you can specify as the followings:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
        new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this)
                .color(Color.RED)
                .sizeResId(R.dimen.divider)
                .marginResId(R.dimen.leftmargin, R.dimen.rightmargin)
                .build());
```