# Android - divider between items in vertical layout

Tags: android, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

I am making something similar to a list view, without actually making a list view...

I have a bunch of text views in a vertical layout, and I am wondering if it is possible to get some sort of divider line in between them. The line dividers like they have in List Views..

Any help?

Comment: you can use this:

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a textview to create a divider line

**Example:**

```
<TextView          
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="1px" 
      android:background="#DADADA" />
```

Comment: Doesn't need to be a TextView, a regular View will do fine and will render faster.

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to give an example.

Comment: You should be using `dp` instead of `px`

Comment: no do not use dp in this instance because android will scale down the 1dp to .75 px on lower dpi screens and that will be 0px.  px is correct

Answer (score 4):

You can insert `View` with background of any color you want and

`layout_height = "1dp"` (or more if necesary) and

`layout_width="fill_parent"`.