# Adding "section dividers" to my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

The [Android Design - Lists](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html) page describes "section dividers". I'm aware you can use `addHeaderView()` a `ListView` for a similar effect. I would like to use a "section divider" without a `ListView`, but rather a `LinearLayout`.

In the screenshot below, I'm referring to the blue text "Phone" and "Email" which also has an line below it. The screenshot is from [Android Design - Text Fields](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/text-fields.html)

[image]

How do I go about adding it to my layout? It it simply a TextView plus a horizontal line?

Comment: Create a background image with a line at the bottom, and set it as background to your TextView.

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction You should write that as an answer since it seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

Comment: [This is my prefered solution from a related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14533085/383414)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was looking for the same issue.
I found an easy way to tell the app that a texview is a section separator:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_label"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address"/>
```

The line:

```
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

add the underline to the text and style it accordingli to the defaulf "Separator" theme.

Comment: How to change the underline's color?

Answer (score 3):

Try to put this View after the TextView of "phone". In this view I have put in a background color that you can change to your desire. Best of luck.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />
```

Comment: Just a quick remark.. With this solution you should use px instead of dip, because in smaller screens it can be converted to 0px and become invisible.

Answer (score 3):

The solution ended up having an includable layout called `util_horizontal_line_section.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="@color/sectionSeparatorColour"/>
```

With the `sectionSeparatorColour` entry in `values/colors.xml`:

```
<color name="sectionSeparatorColour">#a0a0a0</color>
```

Includable via:

```
<include layout="@layout/util_horizontal_line_section"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

On request of the asker of this question, I am writing my comment as an answer

> Create a background image with a line at the bottom, and set it as
>   background to your TextView.

Answer (score -1):

TextView 2dp in height and width = match parent and set the background color as the color you want the line to be.

You can do vertical as well by reversing the two settings.