# Android ListView header: add underline to the header

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with custom adapter and some elements inside. Then I added a header to this listView. The elements in the listView are separated by line and I would like to separate also with a line the header from the first element of the list.

Is that possible? If so, how can I do it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply add one of these answers to the bottom of your header's layout: [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5049852/1267661)

Comment: It works, greqt. Thank you very much Sam. Can you please answer the question so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brought up from comments:**
Simply add one of these answers to the bottom of your header's layout: [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5049852/1267661)

---

I would lean towards the third answer with:

```
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

if you want to mimic the dividers that already exist.

Glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you Sam, I used this answer:  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>