# Vertical Line in Android TableRow Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a seperator line between `TextView` and `EditText` in Android layout. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282253/840566) approach to do it but when i use like it works

```
         <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTrRemainder"
                style="@style/rounded_row" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTvRemainder"
                    style="@style/rounded_label"
                    android:text="Field" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentEtRemainder"
                    style="@style/rounded_value"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:background="#FF909090" />
            </TableRow>
```

[image: Screenshot1]

When i put view between text views like

```
         <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTrRemainder"
                style="@style/rounded_row" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTvRemainder"
                    style="@style/rounded_label"
                    android:text="Field" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:background="#FF909090" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentEtRemainder"
                    style="@style/rounded_value"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>
```

[image: Screenshot2]

I just want a 2pix seperator between TextView and EditText. Any help to achieve this challenge would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rotem gave the correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move your divider view after EditText or wrap EditText and View inside a LinearLayout with weights set to 1 and 0 correspondingly.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
       <View
                android:layout_width="2dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#FF909090" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/frmPaymentEtRemainder"
            style="@style/rounded_value"
            android:editable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just move the View before the EditText. I've missed this part in your description

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the weight attribute

Comment: Nope.. I just tried, and remove both textview's and view's weight, nothing changed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.. in the description you said that you have 2 TextViews but in your code there is only one

Comment: I just want a 2pix seperator between TextView and EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="2dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#FF909090" />`