# Having divider in LinerLayout by using android:divider and android:showDividers

Tags: android

I try to have 2 dividers in between 3 text views. I use `android:divider` and `android:showDividers`. However, no vertical divider being shown. I was wondering, is there anything I had missed out?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dip"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="ABC" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="EFG" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="HIJ" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I usually use simple Views for that.
check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dividers in LinearLayouts are only available from API 11. I assume you are testing on a lower API. See the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setDividerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) for more information. However you can use [IcsLinearlayout](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout.java) from the ABS package for backwards compatibility.

Comment: using the IcsLinearLayout causes a weird error in the graphical designer for the previews , which shows "android.graphics.bitmap_delegate.nativeRecycle(I)Z" . is it possible to avoid it and fix it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper hmm not sure about that. The UI editor tends to have rendering issues a lot, so probably not, sorry.

Comment: but it worked fine before. it happens only when using API17 for the preview.