# How to set divider line between actionbar and split tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm trying to set a 1px divider between my (android) action bar and split tabs below.
how can it be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just put this view between the actionBar and splitTabs

Vertical:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Horizontal:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

[Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

You could do this dynamically the same way as above just in java:

```
View div = new View(this);
div.setBackgroundColor(0xaaaaaa);
div.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(1,-1));
```

I never tested the code but it would be something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure i can do it, since i'm creating the tabs dynamically mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            mDayTab = mActionBar.newTab();
            mDayTab.setText(getString(R.string.day_view));
            mDayTab.setTabListener(this);
            mActionBar.addTab(mDayTab);

Comment: @Gidi did you get the answer? i want also answer. can you help me

Comment: and there is a horizontal divider line (white in my case) below tab bar. I want to remove that divider line. Any idea?