# Android draw a Horizontal line between views

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent

I have My Layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Twitter Feeds"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="FaceBook Feeds" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Requirement is to draw a *Horizontal* line between `TextView` and `ListView`

Could anyone help?

Comment: You can add line to background of existing view's and not add extra one. Or you can put all your views inside listView. listView can draw separators. simplest ways is to add extra view.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

It will draw Silver gray colored Line between `TextView` & `ListView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="FaceBook Feeds" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Comment: This hardcoded color is like using inline css in a webpage. Why is this voted up so much? It should use android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" for example.

Comment: Because it's easy to implement

Comment: @Roel It is simple, easy and it works. And it s straightforward to reference a colour in stead of hardcoding it. I tried your suggestion, which I think would be technically better, but it didn't seem to work - I didn't get any dividers in my layouts. How should I use it? Thank you.

Comment: @Roel What is the downside of using it?

Comment: At least set the colors in a seperate file and use color variables. The downside is that you may have to change many files if you want to change the color / styling of your app.

Answer (score 25):

You should use the new lightweight View `Space` to draw dividers.
Your layout will load faster if you will use `Space` instead of `View`.

Horizontal divider:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Vertical divider:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp" />
```

You can also add a background:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

Usage example:

```
....
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="One"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Two"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Three"/>
....
```

In order to use `Space` you should add the dependency in your **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.+'
}
```

Documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/Space.html

Comment: The use of `Space` is going to be disappointing because `Space` draws nothing (not even a background). It's sole job is to take up space on the screen. The solution is to use a vanilla `View` element instead. Then the background will be drawn as desired. (You can also then avoid the support library dependency if it's not otherwise needed.)

Comment: `Space` inherits from `View` and therefore it inherits all the attributes defined by `View`. (Similarly, `LinearLayout` inherits the `textAlignment` attribute even though it doesn't itself display any text.) Feel free to test this for yourself (or just look at the source code) and you will find that a `Space` ignores all drawing-related attributes.

Comment: Yes, `Space` doesn't draw a background, it's transparent.

Answer (score 23):

add something like this in your layout between the views you want to separate:

```
  <View
       android:id="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height= "2dp"
       android:background="@color/gray" />
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It will draw a Vertical line as its height is match_parent & width is only 2 dp.

Answer (score 20):

Creating it once and using it wherever needed is a good idea. 
Add this in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>
```

and add this in your xml code, where a line divider is needed:

```
<View style="@style/Divider"/>
```

Originally answered by toddles_fp to this question: [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

Comment: wow. This is the best. wish you could also add example to demontsrtae use of vertical and horizontal divders for completeness.

Answer (score 12):

**Try this**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

After many years, finally there is a proper view to display separators/dividers/horizontal lines on XML layouts. The team who develops the Material Components for Android has released the version 1.5.0-alpha01  which adds the `MaterialDivider` class. This allows to add dividers to layouts as said previously.

First, in your build.gradle add the following:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'`

Then, on a XML layout you can write:

```
<com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And voila you have a divider. If you want to customize the color of the divider, there is an xml attribute: `app:dividerColor`. This view also allows theming via styles. For more info you can check this [link](https://material.io/components/dividers/android#theming-dividers).

Answer (score 6):

```
<View
       android:id="@+id/view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="2dp"
       android:background="#000000" />
```

Comment: can't we access this element programatically?

Answer (score 3):

An improvement of the accepted answer by [Bhoomika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2361098/bhoomika-brahmbhatt) for a more polished look:

```
<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/black"
     android:alpha="0.1"/>
```

`android:alpha` is used to set the opacity of views.

Answer (score 2):

You can put this view between your views to imitate the line

```
<View
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this works for me

```
 <View android:layout_width="1dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/tw_composer" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Create Horizontal line**

If your are using TextView and then you want to put a Line then use View
this way and you can use any color like Blue, Red or black mentioning background color.

```
 <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"></view>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In each parent `LinearLayout` for which you want dividers between components, add `android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"` or `android:divider="?android:dividerVertical`.

Choose appropriate between them as per orientation of your `LinearLayout`.

Till I know, this resource style is added from Android 4.3.

Comment: I use almost exclusively constraint layout now but this might come in handy at some point.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

----> Simple one

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    android:id="@+id/your_id"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp" />
```

Comment: nice one. is the View method more versatile?

Answer (score 0):

A View whose background color you can specify would do (height=a few dpi).
Looked in real code and here it is:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lineA"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
```

Note that it may be any kind of `View`.

Answer (score 0):

If you does not want to use an extra view just for underlines. Add this style on your `textView`.

```
style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

Just down side is it will add extra properties like

```
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textAllCaps="true"
```

which you can easily override.

Answer (score 0):

which work for me is

```
    <view
    android:layout_below="@+id/kaimla_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/golden"></view>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <view
        android:id="@+id/blackLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

Comment: you are not supposed to add only screenshots instead of code on StackOverflow or any other online forum. This makes it harder for anyone trying to test or implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

with this view tag you can make a view horizontally or vertically simply can make it horizontal and vertical by making changes into height and width.horizontal and vertical line you can simply make.
this is horizontal line code in which the hieght if the view is thickness of line.

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/green"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgChoice" />
```