# How to make the Borders of a custom button in android

Tags: android, button, divider

I want to achieve something like this :

[image: See two Buttons at the bottom]

I want to make the button transparent Which I have successfully done, now tell me how can I show the line on the upper border of the button and between the two button. How can I handle this. my xml of button is simply goes like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Send Message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#ff4444"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#ff4444"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

So How can I achieve the borders like this as shown in picture below. 
pardon me , for the small size picture as I have this only single image to clear my question .

Comment: Show A View above the button if you wish

Comment: you mean to put an image view ?

Comment: No a `View` like 
`<View
android:layout_height = "2dip" 
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
android:background="#FEFEFE"/>`

Comment: how about between the buttons

Comment: Provide the same view, make height of view same as buttons, and width to `2dip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to add **separator line**, please add this:

```
<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

I would use realitveLayout instad of LinearLayout, so you can set the position of the separators more quickly. You are going to have 2 separators, one is the horizontal, with layout_width="match_parent" and one between the elements.

[Android draw a Horizontal line between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115332/android-draw-a-horizontal-line-between-views)

[Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

You can define your own shape and add to the **Button, as background:**
use it as R.drawable.myshape:

place it to res/drawable/myshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFEEE" 
    android:endColor="#00FFFF"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <stroke android:width="7px" android:color="#EE0FF0" />
</shape>
```

if you would like to be **transparent** as well, try this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="1.4"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="4dp"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
 </shape>
```

Comment: stroke will give you borders

Comment: would it make the buttons hollow ?

Comment: it is giving me borders on all four side where as I just want to put line or divider at their top and one between them as shown in image above.

Comment: bah,sorry I totally misunderstood you. You have to define your own separators, plesae see my edited answer

Comment: for some reasons I have defined my root layout to some size , so in your edited answer its width is fill parent , so line/separator is sticking out the main view , how can I handle this? <all I want is to ask is that How can i keep the width as the parent layout , so that I can get rid of handling it again in xml in dps or in java class. ,>

Comment: all I wanted to ask is that , is there any way , that if i have described a specific width or height of layout , then its child layout take the width of what the parent layout have ? is my question is clear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81507/discussion-between-stacy-queen-and-karoly).

Comment: to have the child view the same with as it`s parent, you should say: match_parent.