# create below layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to create below layout in **XML**. I am able to create circle but I don't know how to connect them by a horizontal line:

[image]

Comment: Use Html to draw horizontal line

Comment: Put a generic View in between the TextViews, with a fixed height of 1dp (or what you see fit). And as a background, use a color.

Comment: in Android XML how to use that?

Comment: Draw a line like  @FrankN.Stein said, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115332/android-draw-a-horizontal-line-between-views

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
.......
......>
       <CircleView..../>
       <View 
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="@color/circle_color"/>
       <CircleView..../>

       <View 
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="@color/circle_color"/>

       <CircleView..../>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give some more piece of code for clarity

Comment: you can create circle drawable for normal and selected view take checkbox instead of CircleView apply selector to checkbox, sma you can do to line selector

Answer (score 0):

Generally these (step-by-step) indicators are implemented using different images loaded via single `ImageView`. Just load the appropriate `drawable` for a particular step. This way you need not worry about writing/arranging lot of UI `widgets` in `xml`.

I am attaching sample images for your reference:

step 1 of 4: 
[image]

step 2 of 4: 
[image]

step 3 of 4: 
[image]

step 4 of 4: 
[image]

Comment: Can i do this by xml without using images?

Comment: You surely can but you will have to write quite a lot views for that (5 views for a 3 step process) and arranging those horizontal connectors between the circular views will take some time. Moreover, if you choose to change the layout in future then it will be a complete rework. :)