# How to set group divider color for ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]

I can set the devider color for the children using childDivider attribute (black in this example). But, I don't see any way to set the color of the divider between the collapsed groups. System seems to be showing a 1px white line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The color of the divider line when a group is closed can be set via:

```
android:divider
```

The color of the divider lines when a group is opened aka. the child is visible can be set via:

```
android:childDivider
```

Comment: Yes, android:divider does what I want. For details, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17081865/1036017

Answer (score 2):

**For Group:**

```
<item name="android:groupIndicator">@android:drawable/expander_group</item>
```

**For Children:**

```
<item name="android:childDivider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark_opaque</item>
```

---

**All the ExpandableListView traits:**

```
<style name="Widget.ExpandableListView" parent="Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:groupIndicator">@android:drawable/expander_group</item>
    <item name="android:indicatorLeft">?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft</item>
    <item name="android:indicatorRight">?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight</item>
    <item name="android:childDivider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark_opaque</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ExpandableListView.White">
    <item name="android:childDivider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque</item>
</style>
```

Comment: groupIndicator sets the icon next to the group's title. It doesn't set the separator color between collapsed group views.

Comment: Updated answer with all of the customizable parts to an Expandable ListView.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I am not looking for child divider color. I am looking for group divider, which is currently white in my screenshot. if you think that you are correct, please explain more. As it stands, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I'm simply letting you know what's customizable with what you're using. You have to figure out what works.