# Add Separator in TableLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have created a `TableLayout` and placed it inside a `ScrollView`. Now I have created row of `TableLayout` using `RelativeLayout` rather than `TableRow`. Now I have a question that can we add seperator in `TableLayout` wheteher data is available or not, means, if data is not available then separator will shown. Another question is, can we scroll the table if only two rows are shown in table.

Please help me for the same.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be you can add a separator as in this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout>

Answer (score 0):

Add A separator by

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

or programatically as

> TextView v = new TextView(contex);
>
> v.setHeight(1);
>
> v.setWidht(MATCH_PARENT):

You can scroll only if the tablelayout is after more than fully occupied