# android TextView with line after text

Tags: android, textview

how I can achieve one thing as in the example
TextView with a line after the text

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdos5.png)

Comment: what is the use of that line?is it for user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way this worked for me

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
      android:text="Heelloos"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

   <View
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:background="#ff00ff"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for adding line check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282253/3746306).

and align this view to the rightOf your text view.
done

Answer (score 0):

Try with this answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Your Message: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```