# <br> between android xml tags

Tags: android, html, xml

I have begin to use the xml in Android Studio, and mostly the RelativeLayout. Then, I knew that in HTML, when I use a tag like p or button and I want, for example, button is under p, I do:

```
<p>Hello</p><br><button value="World"></button>
```

Then, I want this result with 2 TextView.
This is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I don't want to put a TextView under another TextView because THE TEXTVIEW MUST NOT HAVE AN ID.

Comment: so what you want to do , i didnt understand can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Why shouldn't the textview have an ID?

Comment: Because I'm making an application that it include an xml code from an external file and this external file hasn't got the IDs

Comment: my friend what you want to put , if you dont want to put TextView ?

Comment: XML is not a visual representation language like HTML. It is data representation language and here in android it is used to represent elements. So you must have some element between two text fields to separate. for example : a divider line. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)