# android studio design line break

Tags: android, line

Someone knows how to insert that type of lines separating the textview fields ?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Add this snippet in your xml file: 
    <View android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="3px" 
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

`<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>`

Comment: better use ?android:attr/listDivider as background for consistency across devices and os

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

anyway you can look it up more on:

[Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to draw the line between the textViews and put margins on the left and right side

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="#000" />
```