# I want to add divider line between two views in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add divider (a smooth transparent line between two views either horizontally or vertically )how can i achieve this here is my sample code.i need to add horizontal line between username and password(horizontally) and also between user icon and username hint(vertically)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/liner"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/user"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:textColor="#bbc"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/usr_name"
                android:textColorHint="#bbc"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/paswd"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:textColor="#bbc"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/passwd"
                android:textColorHint="#bbc"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please do google before asking such question

Comment: Please [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

Comment: try to find on your side at least once.

Answer (score 3):

for horizontal Line

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="username"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:textColor="#bbc"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ebebeb"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="usr_name"
            android:textColorHint="#bbc"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

for vertical line

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#cd2121"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_10">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="password"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:textColor="#bbc"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="your color"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="password"
            android:textColorHint="#bbc"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a drawable file of below code, for divider line, and use it wherever you need, also change color according to your choice.

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.7dp"
    android:background="#ebebeb" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Between the two linear layout for username and password use the following:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0.5dp"
android:background="#cd2121" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create another view  in between userName & passowrd

```
<View 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="2dp"
 android:color="@color/divider_color"
 android:id="@+id/divider" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a divider by using the `View` tag with a height (or width if it's vertical) of 1dp between the views you want to divide:

```
<View
 android:id="@+id/line"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="@color/yourColor/>
```