# Scrollview not scrolling with a constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am having some issues with scroll view. My scrollview contains a parent constraint layout, which further contains two more constraint layouts, and two buttons. The child constraint layout at the bottom contains a listview, that is populated at runtime. In order to take advantage of the scroll view, I did the following:

1. Set the height of listview to wrap_content.
2. Set the height of the second child constraint layout (containing the listview) as wrap_content.
3. Set the height of the parent constraint layout (containing the two child constraint layout) to wrap_content.
4. Set the height of the root view, that is the scrollview to be wrap_content.

PS: After the two child constraint layouts, there are two buttons in the parent constraint layout.

But the result is, scrolling does not go beyond the third item in the listview (I have total of 5 items in the list view), also the buttons are not visible (they are out of the screen, below).
If someone could help me in identifying the possible issues, that will be great. Googling wasn't much of a help.

Here is my code: (child items are jumbled up)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".view.Vote"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_vote">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/electionDetailsHeaderCardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#FDD700"
                app:cardElevation="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/electionDetailsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Election detail"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/electionDescriptionTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/electionDetailsHeaderCardView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="@string/medium_text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/electionDescriptionTextView" />

            <!--Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282253/5394180 (divider)-->
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/electionDetailsHeaderCardView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/importantHeaderTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Important"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/electionDescriptionTextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/electionDescriptionTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startLabelTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Start:"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/importantHeaderTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/finishLabelTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Finish:"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/startLabelTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startDateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text=" 23/03/2019, 00:00:00"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/startLabelTextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/startLabelTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/finishDateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="30/03/2019, 00:00:00"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/finishLabelTextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/finishLabelTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/statusLabelTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Status:"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/finishLabelTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Finish"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/statusLabelTextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/statusLabelTextView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/statusLabelTextView" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/electionCandidatesHeaderCardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#FDD700"
                app:cardElevation="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/electionCandidatesHeaderTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Election candidates"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/candidateListView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/electionCandidatesHeaderCardView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateListView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/voteButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="Vote"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateListView" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I tried googling for this thing. I saw some related results, but I wasn't able to solve my issue following them. The results were pretty specific to the asker's code.

Comment: Hi, just confirming are you using a listview or a recyclerview? If recyclerview I think you'd need to set it to setnestedscroll = false programmatically for the whole view scroll instead of just the list and all the elements on the view to be shown. Not sure about listview though.

Comment: I am using a listview with a custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry not sure what to do in this case.