# Should I use a list view or View to create the lines below the user's information as shown in this image?

Tags: android, android-layout

To create this UI would it be best to use a simple list view or to create a view with a line as the background? I am unsure as to what would be the proper way of doing this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsgrJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView would make your code more maintainable, but if it's just static elements on the screen and you're sure you're not going to add anything, you could definitely use a simple View.
i use LinearLayouts for underlines like those.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#52525252"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using a LinearLayout isn't great for performance, better to just use a `View`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout

Comment: You can use View or Horizontal deivider widget for create divider line

Answer (score 0):

This is a best way to add static underline ,Use View to add static underline

Add this Code:

```
          <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#52525252"/>
```

[image: screen shot]